# Convert hexadecimal unicode character into its visual representation

Tags: c#, unicode, char, hex

I am trying to make a C# program that translates unicode character from its hexadecimal format to a single character, and I have a problem. This is my code:

This works:

```
char e = Convert.ToChar("\u0066");
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
Console.WriteLine("enter unicode format character (for example \\u0066)");
string s = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("you entered (for example f)");
char c = Convert.ToChar(s);
```

Because `(Convert.ToChar("\\u0066"))` gives the error:

> String must be exactly one character long

Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

int.Parse doesn't like the "\u" prefix, but if you validate first to ensure that it's there, you can use

```
char c = (char)int.Parse(s.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

This strips the first two characters from the input string and parses the remaining text.

In order to ensure that the sequence is a valid one, try this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})$");
if( reg.IsMatch(s) )
{
  char c = (char)int.Parse(s.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}
else
{
  // Error
}
```

Comment: That's not quite it either.  It would allow parsing `\u       a` and `\u1234567890`, neither of which are valid unicode character constants.

Comment: Indeed, hence the need to validate the input value first.

Comment: @Steve: Yes!!!! Thank you so much!! Actually, validate first two character will be enough for me since if sequence starting with \u it must be proper hexadecimal sequence since I catch that improper sequences earlier. You save my day :)

Comment: Since you captured the hexadecimal digits using the regex, why not use the capture group (instead of calling substring and building yet another string)?  And `AllowHexSpecifier` would still be better than `HexNumber`, ignoring spaces is neither necessary nor desirable.

Comment: *checks spec* - Yes @Ben, I agree! Though the regex is going to ensure that there are no spaces present, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> Convert.ToChar("\u0066");
> ```

This is a one-character string at run-time, because the compiler processed the backslash sequence.

The rest of your code is dealing with six character strings `{ '\\', 'u', '0', '0', '6', '6' }`, which `Convert.ToChar` cannot handle.

Try [`char.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.parse.aspx) (or possibly `Int16.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)` followed by a cast to `char`).

Comment: Neither of those work, because char.parse will still only accept a single character and Int16.Parse doesn't support a unicode specifier.

Comment: @Steve: Well, you need to pull out the hexadecimal digits from the string using a regular expression or similar.